Family movie with multiracial kids and adoption from last 10 years
Some time ago I saw an interesting family movie, but I forgot name and don't know any of actors either. The story basically started with Christian missionary parents dying and leaving their kids behind - the oldest was their own by blood, the rest was originally adopted from different places around the world. One boy came from Africa, another from South America, a little girl from Thailand and so on.
In their last will they asked their best friend (female singer, and her husband was also in the music industry) to take care of the kids in case of death. That "music industry couple" didn't have their own kids and were used to live their lives focused on career so having a house full of kids presented a new challenge for them. At the same time the kids moving from Africa to a modern American school gave them their own challenges while clashing with cultural and worldview differences with other kids of their age.
The end of movie is easy to predict - the new family comes together for real and there is some concert with the new singer mom and family. But the interaction on the way there between couple and kids and between kids and their peers is what was best about this movie.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released?  What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Laguage-English,, Released - few years back(no idea of exact year),, Country - USA (probably),, Time period of movie - present

How many is a "few"? 5 years, 10...15?

I srsly dont know year of release, my best guess is 2013 +- few years

I'm guessing it is Change of Plans
Excerpts from user reviews on IMDB:
"The story is about Sally Danville (played by Brooke White) and Jason Danville (played by Joe Flanigan) who are having great careers and great prospects for the future, when they are trusted with the well-being and caring for the four children of Sally's friend and her husband, who died in an accident. And they have to adjust to family life, putting their own needs on hold and making big sacrifices."
AND:
"At the start of the movie, Sally is performing music that could be country, alternative rock or classic rock. Someone would have to tell me. Then she goes to pick up her husband Dan, a former Air Force pilot who now designs fighter planes, at the local Air Force base.
As the couple prepares to go on a much-needed vacation in Tahiti, the phone rings. Sally's former best friend Teresa and her husband Frank have been killed. Teresa's will leaves their biological daughter Jordan and their three adopted children to Sally. Teresa and Frank were in Uganda serving in the Peace Corps. Kaleb is from Uganda, Javier is Latino and Sung-Lee is from China."

I know i wasnt completly correct so i am so much more grateful for your help with finding this movie name.

You were pretty close - just the husband was not in the music industry  - happy to help - you had enough detail for me to search.
